# SlideToggle multiple divs in a Repeater

Tags: jquery, asp.net, repeater, slidetoggle, itemtemplate

I am using below code to SlideToggle the divs in a Repeater.
Since it is a repeater I unable to capture the correct id for the second div. When I click on the bar, the SlideToggle for Description works correctly but the location for all the items in ItemTemplate toggles at the sametime irrespective of which item's bar is clicked.
What is the right way to slideToggle multiple divs in a repeater?  Please see the below code:

```
<ItemTemplate>
<div class="memberImage">
<asp:Image ImageUrl="~/Content/images/image1.jpg" runat="server"/>
 <div id="location" style="background-color:lightgrey; width:180px; height:200px; display:none;z-index:-30;margin-top: -20px;">

  </div>
</div>

<div class="memData">

   <div id="blueBar">
       <div id="Title"><%# Eval("title") %> </div>

       <asp:ImageButton style="margin-left:420px;" ID="ImageButton1" width="60" Height="60" ImageUrl="~/Content/images/down_arrow_white.png" runat="server" />

    </div>

    <div id="Description" style="display:none;" >
        <p> <%# Item.Description %></p>
     </div>
</div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

and the jQuery code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {


        $('[id*="blueBar"]').click(function () {

            $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");

            $('[id*="location"]').slideToggle("slow");

        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to wrap your `Repeater` `ItemTemplate` into a container `div`, as below.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="memberImage">
            <asp:Image ImageUrl="~/Content/images/image1.jpg" runat="server"/>
            <div class="location" style="background-color:lightgrey; width:180px; height:200px; display:none;z-index:-30;margin-top: -20px;">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="memData">
            <div class="blueBar">
                <div id="Title"><%# Eval("title") %> </div>
                <asp:ImageButton style="margin-left:420px;" ID="ImageButton1" width="60" Height="60" ImageUrl="~/Content/images/down_arrow_white.png" runat="server" />
            </div>
            <div id="Description" style="display:none;" >
                <p> <%# Item.Description %></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Use `class` instead of `id` for both **blueBar** and **location** divs.

Modify your jQuery part as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.blueBar').click(function () {
            $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");

            //for location div you will need to traverse the DOM as below
            $(this).parent().sibling().find('.location').show().slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: :Thanks for your response Devraj! I did exactly what you suggested but location is not visible.The toggle for Description works but location doesn't appear at all. Am I missing something?

Comment: @bunnie, see my edited answer now, I missed that you had given `style="display:none;"`. You can use jQuery functions `.hide()` and `.show()` to hide or show any DOM element.